# CSRF token with multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I have two forms on a single page, both of which are declared like this:

`form_for @student, {remote:true, format: 'json'} do |f|`

and

`form_for @teacher, {remote:true, format: 'json'} do |f|`

However, when I click the submit button for the `teacher` form, it errors out, saying "Invalid CRSF token" for that request. The requests for the `student` form work fine.

I've got `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in the main `application.html.erb` file, and the `teacher` form does have a CSRF token in the submit. I'm not doing an API, I just want the form to be handled via AJAX (I do some client-side error handling and confirmation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to disable CSRF protection for json requests, according to the Rails docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

> It's important to remember that XML or JSON requests are also affected
>   and if you're building an API you'll need something like:
>
> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   protect_from_forgery
>   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?
>
>   protected
>
>   def json_request?
>     request.format.json?
>   end
> end
> ```

See also:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3041
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Comment: Hm interesting, I never knew that. It works now, so thank you very much!

Comment: Won't this solution leave you exposed to CSRF attacks?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes it would. That's an important factor when considering this solution.